# How to get image uri from drawable folder in android 12 or higher?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a share intent in my android app which works well on android 11 and below but **in android 12 it crashes becuase I'm using insertImage() [a deprecated method] to get the image uri** .
My code is as follows:

```
val path = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.share)
//the below line has the insertImage() which is deprecated.
           val path1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(contentResolver,path,"title",null)
           val uri = Uri.parse(path1)
           val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
           action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
           putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi")
           putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri)
           flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
           type = "image/*"
                                }
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "null"))
```

I have tried almost all solutions on stackoverflow, none of them resolves my issue as they are all either outdated or just another explanations.

Any Help Regarding this issue Is welcomed!

Comment: Why are you calling a bitmap 'path'? Unreadable code.

Comment: You should have posted the stacktrace from logcat with the FileUriExposedException that you did not catch so your app crashed.

Comment: i don't find any error/warning but only get a [blank image](https://i.ibb.co/CKg7ftB/Screenshot-20230114-144041.png) . And in log cat, ` 466-505/? W/TransactionTracing: Could not find layer handle 0x73abdd22d4d0 `

Comment: Then what goes wrong? At which statement does it crash?

Comment: And where do you get a blank image? You are not displaying your bitmap so where do you see it?

Comment: i am displaying my bitmap in share intent . [see here](https://i.ibb.co/RvSzNqt/Screenshot-20230114-145850.png)

Comment: As u can see in the above comment, it just displays like a file icon instead of img

Comment: And where does it crash then? And when?

Comment: it crashed on android 12 as i used a deprecated method. not the one u said

Comment: Your deprecated method has nothing to do with FileProvider. Its no replacement for it. Pretty unclear what happens. Now tell which statement lets your app crash? And the subject of your post is strange as you are sharing.

Comment: it doesn't crash on emulators. but only the release apk crashes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + 
    packageName + "/drawable" + '/' + 
    resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.share))
val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi")
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri)
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    type = "image/*"
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "null"))
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work instead it just returns a blank/invalid file on sharing

Comment: Few apps support the `android.resource` scheme.

Comment: oh so, is there any solution to get a uri for a drawable in android 12?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileProvider to share your path 'path1'.

Comment: thanks for answering, I would appreciate some example/ code instead of just explaining.

Comment: I did not explain anything. I told how it should be done.

Comment: so how to use file provider in my case?

Comment: Like in any other case. Examples all over the internet.

Comment: all those examples doesn't work for me . but just returns the same type of blank image

Comment: i don't wish use a file from device. i just want to get the uri of a drawable img

Comment: A file in drawable resource has no uri. But what you can do is make a bitmap of it. Then save the bitmap to file. Then use FileProvider to get an uri for the file path.

Comment: `don't wish use a file from device. ` ? But you do. You use the mediastore and a deprecated method to save your bitmap to storage as a file.

Comment: thank you! & can u pls atleast include a link for an example on how to save bitmap to file?

Comment: You are already saving to file i told you already. You use the MediaStore for it. Look at the value of 'path1'.

Comment: thank you! i got what u said, so how to use fileprovider instead? i don't find any updated method that returns the uri

Comment: My god... Instead of what? You have a 'path1'. Use  FileProvider.getUriForFile() on that path.

Comment: path1 is deprecated right? :)